# The Reason of Service Termination

Tags: delphi, service

I use a service application I created in Delphi. My problem is that it is sometimes terminated by the operating system and I don't know why this happens.

When I go the the system events, I can find a piece of information like this one:

[Event ID: 7034](http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=7034&eventno=1424&source=Service%20Control%20Manager&phase=1), The [...] service terminated unexpectedly. It has done this [...] time(s).

I know you can't give me an answer why this happens, but could you please give me a clue what to pay attention to to find the reason of that behaviour? For instance what kind of exceptions could make the OS close an application.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it is the OS terminating your service? It looks your service is crashing, and the OS simply records it. I'd suggest you to trap exceptions in your service threads main loop, and write them to the event log.

Comment: I have forgotten to say that it is a multithreaded application, uses an MSSQL database and executes queries all the time. I don't know whether this matters. I use dbExpress controls.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know whether it is the OS that terminates my service. The only thing I know is that from time to time I can see my service not running and then those system events informing about a crash...

Comment: OK, I'll try to catch exceptions in the main thread, but are you sure that it is only the main thread that can make an application terminate?

Comment: Have you googled for "service terminated unexpectedly"?  That's what I usually do when I encounter a meaningless error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make a debug version with [Eurekalog](http://www.eurekalog.com/) or [MadExcept](http://www.madshi.net/), and it'll tell you where it's blowing up, what the stack looked like, memory, etc..

They can also auto-restart your app. Not sure if that can be done on a service, but for regular apps, it can. They can also send you the dump via e-mail, or even post directly to a bug tracker like FogBugz or Mantis.  These measures will be helpful in the event that you don't find a smoking gun right away, and need to keep troubleshooting/debugging in place as a long-term solution.  i.e. even if something only crashes once a month or even once a year, it's easier to tell your boss "I'm looking at the logs" than "I really have no idea".

Comment: I like this approach :-). In fact the unexpected termination happens once every few days or even weeks and you are right - it is better to tell your boss that you are checking the logs instead of saying you have no idea :). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are capturing all exceptions within the Execute method of all your threads Assuming your are using TThread descendants). If any get through to the OS this might cause it to terminate your service.

Comment: +1, very good advice (in general, not only for threads in services).

Comment: I think there is a try/except section in each Execute method in my service, but I will check that to be sure. Thanks for the advice.